# Folder permission denied

Tags: php

I am working on a compression script. it reads the directories and compress the files and folder and moves compressed files/folder to a **Out** folder.

When i create folders in side the **Out** from my php script i dont have write access to to those folders there afeter, but when tried with cmd it isn't .its like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root      root      4096 Jan 30 08:25 erik 
drwxr-xr-x 6 root      root      4096 Jan 27 11:39 gayan 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root      root      4096 Jan 27 12:00 iyan 
**drwxr-xr-x 5 root      root      4096 Jan 30 09:50 Samuli** 
drwxrwxr-x 2 plusmedia plusmedia 4096 Jan 30 09:56 ssss
```

what would cause this? any solution is admire, Thanks

Comment: Either alter the permissions of the folder so that your web server can access it or get someone who can do so to do so.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for my question ,
Its all about the user permission problem where my script run as root user and i am trying to modify the folders by another user that doesn't have permission as root. 

So i managed to get rid.
Thanks @Sabari in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the current user with which you are executing the php script do not have permission to write in that folder. You could switch to root user through terminal and then:

```
chmod 777 -R /path/to/your/Outfolder
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks but i have full access on the root folder so it wouldn't be the matter

Comment: logged in user **Plusmedia** has full access control to the folder that i can create and delete folders on cmd but this happens when i create a directory with my php script

Comment: What is your php script to create file. Can you paste it. Which is your OS??

Comment: Cent OS `if(chdir($root7zDir)){
                 
                 if(!file_exists($plazaFolders))mkdir($plazaFolders,0777);
                 chdir($root7zDir.$plazaFolders);
                 if(!file_exists($projectFolders))mkdir($projectFolders,0777);
                 if(!file_exists($tempFolders))mkdir($tempFolders,0777);
             if(!file_exists($completeFolders))mkdir($completeFolders,0777);  chdir($rootDir.$plazaFolders.'/'.$projectFolders);      if(system('mv '.$files.'.7z '.$root7zDir.$plazaFolders.'/'.$projectFolders)){   print("\t\t $files.'.7z' moved to Out_7z  ...\n") }`

Comment: when i create `$projectFolders`

Comment: I am not sure what the error is. Its working for me. Make sure $projectFolders Path is correct

Comment: Thanks for taking time for my question ,
Its all about the user permission problem where my script run as root user and i am trying to modify the folders by another user that doesn't have permission as root. 

So i managed to get rid.
Thanks @Sabari in Advance.